# Create a vector of pointers to abstract objects

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

I'm trying to create a class `HashTable` that is given a size at instantiation, so it can't be given a size at design time, so I can't use an array as my internal representation of the table, as far as I know.

So here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Nodes.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class HashTable{

protected:
    vector<* TableNode<T>> myTable;
    //other protected methods go here

public:
    HashTable(int size){
        myTable = vector<* TableNode<T>>(size,NULL);
    }

//The rest of the class
};
```

From what I've seen, vector is the best data structure to use here, because it will let me give it a size in the constructor, and lets me use `myTable[index]` style notation to access its contents. However, VS2010 doesn't like my use of `vector<* TableNode<T>>` and I can't say I blame it. So, how do I create an array or vector or whatever of pointers to `TableNode<T>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the asterisk around:

```
vector<TableNode<T>*> myTable;

myTable = vector<TableNode<T>*>(size,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<TableNode<T>*> myTable;
myTable = vector<TableNode<T>*>(size,NULL);
```

FTFY.